# Content-Disposition Security

Tags: python, security, flask

So here's the setup:

I have a simple Flask app with Flask-WTF.

A user submits a form with one text field - `filename`.

The form has a CSRF token (from Flask-WTF.)

If a user submits the form and validates, then the browser downloads an autogenerated file (i.e. not a file from the server filesystem) with the filename submitted.

The important code is:

```
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}.lsc'.format(filename)
```

How safe is that?

In other words what could a malicious user possibly do if they could insert arbitrary text into the `Content-Disposition` header?

Comment: What do you mean by an autogenerated file? Where does the file come from?

Comment: It is generated upon request. I.e. It takes a template, and inserts data from the session and then streams it as a downloaded file. As a note, the filename variable is not used in the template. In fact it is used only in the code line provided.

Comment: I'd check that the server side language is not vulnerable to header injection (e.g. if `filename` contains new line characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They won't be able to do anything to the server, and it should be safe on the client side if they implement [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) properly:

> The receiving user agent SHOULD NOT respect any directory path
>   information present in the filename-parm parameter, which is the only
>   parameter believed to apply to HTTP implementations at this time. The
>   filename SHOULD be treated as a terminal component only.

However, for a full consideration of this issue, see [RFC 2183: Communicating Presentation Information in Internet Messages: The Content-Disposition Header Field](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt), specifically the Security Considerations section. (RFC 2183 applies to mail messages, but is equally applicable to HTTP user agents.)